# Scraping in multiple classes Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to extract text in the following HTML inside the `class="a-size-based-plus a-color-base"` using selenium webdriver.

[image: Scraping the text inside the blue line]

My code structure is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located

import os
import re  # regular expressions, are imported from python directly
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

-----HERE is some unrelated code-----

```
# Find Data
    i = 0
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CLASS_NAME, 'xtaqv-root')))
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'extension-rank')))
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-src="price"]')))
    time.sleep(5)

    for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('xtaqv-root'):   
        # Ratio of similarity
        try:
            item_name = element.find_element_by_tag_name("h2").text
            ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, item_name, key).ratio()
        except:
            item_name = np.nan
            ratio = 0
            pass
        try:
            link = element.find_element_by_css_selector('[data-src="price"]')
            href = link.get_attribute('href')
        except:         
            href = np.nan
        try:
            brand = element.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-size-based-plus.a-color-base')
            brand = brand.text
        except:         
            brand = np.nan
```

**The last try-except in the code is the most important.**

Comment: You haven't said what issue/error you are facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the HTML, I see a typo in your locator, this line:

```
brand = element.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-size-based-plus.a-color-base')
```

It should be `size-base` not `size-based`, try this:

```
brand = element.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-size-base-plus.a-color-base')
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Haha, thank you @DebanjanB :) I hope it was the issue.

Comment: It worked!! I did a little amendment too `brand = element.find_element_by_css_selector('.a-size-base-plus.a-color-base').text`